# iterating document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Hi guys i'm trying to iterate a getElementsByClassName in this way:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
if (document.getElementsByClassName("available")[i]==="undefined"){}
else{
 document.getElementsByClassName("available")[i].click();  }



}
```

if i do it in chrome console it works fine , but when i run it trough my chrome extension it says read property 'click' of undefined , do you know how i can solve?

Comment: yes here is a screen https://i.gyazo.com/0459fbaf456070644b691e5443620d68.png

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("available")[i]` will never equal `"undefined"` (the string). It may equal `undefined` (not a string) but not `"undefined"`. Also why not use the `length` of the collection.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("available")[i].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}))

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```js
var available = document.getElementsByClassName("available"); //collection of elements matching the query

//Loop collection. 
//Skips loop if the available collection is empty
for (var i = 0; i < available.length; i++) {
    available[i].click();
}
```

Comment: Good answer! By the way, `document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, it returns a collection (an HTMLCollection to be exact)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I updated the comments to reflect the proper data type. :)

Comment: ok this works in chrome console, but not in my chrome extension

Comment: now even in chrome console says this and doesn't work https://gyazo.com/84afbe2f1961e99fa850b40cc311fd4d

Comment: it works only if i have my mouse on the element ... but idk why

Comment: I think for us to help you further we will need to see some of the code surrounding this snippet. It sounds like something else is going on.

Comment: that's a thir part website: what i can see from the console is that when i hover on the class the class change it's name to "mouseover"

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement isn't working as you're not checking to see whether the type of the target element is undefined. Try this instead -

```
document.getElementsByClassName("available")[i]===undefined
```